# SQL CASE WHEN- can I do a function within a function? New to SQL

Tags: sql, function, case, razorsql

```
SELECT
        SP.SITE,
        SYS.COMPANY,
        SYS.ADDRESS,
        SP.CUSTOMER,
        SP.STATUS,
        DATEDIFF(MONTH,SP.MEMBERSINCE, SP.EXPIRES) AS MONTH_COUNT
CASE WHEN(MONTH_COUNT = 0 THEN MONTH_COUNT = DATEDIFF(DAY,SP.MEMBERSINCE, SP.EXPIRES) AS DAY_COUNT)
ELSE NULL
END
    FROM SALEPASSES AS SP
    INNER JOIN SYSTEM AS SYS ON SYS.SITE = SP.SITE
    WHERE STATUS IN (7,27,29);
```

I am still trying to understand SQL. Is this the right order to have everything? I'm assuming my datediff() is unable to work because it's inside case when. What I am trying to do, is get the day count if month_count is less than 1 (meaning it's less than one month and we need to count the days between the dates instead). I need month_count to run first to see if doing the day_count would even be necessary. Please give me feedback, I'm new and trying to learn!

Comment: `MONTH_COUNT =` isn't allowed at that place

Comment: What SQL engine? Off the top of my head, it looks like you're trying to use the MONTH_COUNT from your SELECT inside your CASE.  it won't work that way. You have to do the same SQL inside your when clause again.

Comment: RazorSQL is just an editor, it doesn't impact anything in terms of the language. Are you using MS SQL Server? If so, what version?

Answer (score 1):

`Case` is an *expression*, it *returns* a value, it *looks* like you should be doing this:

```
DAY_COUNT =
 CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MONTH,SP.MEMBERSINCE, SP.EXPIRES) = 0 
 THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,SP.MEMBERSINCE, SP.EXPIRES)) 
 ELSE NULL END
```

You shouldn't actually need `else null` as NULL is the default.

Note also you [usually] cannot refer to a derived column in the same *select*

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you are trying to do is define the MonthCount column's value, and then reuse that value in another column's definition. *(The **Don't Repeat Yourself** principle.)*

In most dialects of SQL, you can't do that. Including MS SQL Server.

That's because SQL is a "declarative" language. This means that SQL Server is free to calculate the column values in any order that it likes. In turn, that means you're not allowed to do anything that would rely on one column being calculated before another.

There are two basic ways around that...

First, use CTEs or sub-queries to create two different "scopes", allowing you to define MonthCount before DayCount, and so reuse the value without retyping the definition.

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE WHEN MonthCount = 0 THEN foo ELSE NULL END AS DayCount
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    bar   AS MonthCount
  FROM
    x
)
  AS derive_month
```

The second main way is to somehow derive the value Before the SELECT block is evaluated. In this case, using APPLY to 'join' a single value on to each input row...

```
SELECT
  x.*,
  MonthCount,
  CASE WHEN MonthCount = 0 THEN foo ELSE NULL END AS DayCount
FROM
  x
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    bar   AS MonthCount
)
  AS derive_month
```